# Selenium Webhook equivalent / listen to new data from telegram without bot

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, telegram-webhook

I have a web scraping project that requires the scraper to wait for when there is new data. I thought about reverse engineering the websocket but that might take some time.

> *if you know how to work with the telegram websockets to get data **without a bot** I'd appreciate it*

So what I will need to do is get the web scraper to wait for new messages on a telegram chat and only execute action when a new message is detected, it might need work with javascript event listeners or something but I wanted to ask for the most efficient solution for the given problem.
thanks

Comment: Is it a private chat, channel or group?

Comment: @soundwave it is a private group, but generally even if there is no true way to add webhooks through telegram, I'd like to know how it would work with selenium (or even puppeteer if it was a better solution)